# Angular 2: Content reprojection with multiple targets

Tags: angular

I'm playing around with Content Reprojection ("transclusion") and multiple targets in Anguar 2. For this, I've created a component option-item that can be used the following way:

```
<option-item #i2 value="2" (change)="change()">
    <span class="label">Some Label</span>
    <span class="text">Some Text</span>
</option-item>
```

The label and the text are projected to different positions within the view of the option-item. For this, I'm using something like

```
<content select=".label">
```

When there are NO whitespaces between the projected tags, everything works fine. If there are whitespaces, like above, where you find tabs and line-breaks within the option-item-tag, Angular 2 throws the following exception:

```
TypeError: n.msMatchesSelector is not a function
```

Now I'm wondering, how to tell Angular 2 to ignore those whitespaces. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: Could you set a plunkr? That might be a bug.

Comment: I've put the sample here: http://plnkr.co/edit/wGY3U9okwCHiiFcHFe3s?p=preview

Comment: Just tweak the comments in app.html to switch between the two Versions (with and without whitespace)

Comment: I think I made it work, I think... First upgrade your angular version to alpha32, then [change `<content>` to `<ng-content>`](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3301) and finally [change @Parent to @Ancestor](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/3159). See if that works in both cases. Here's your [plnkr updated](http://plnkr.co/edit/Smh3KOaQ5pI8RVxwhzV3?p=preview)

Comment: Great. Works like a charm. So it was due to the used alpha ...